# Express limit of sum in terms of definite integral

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Evaluate the limit by expressing it as a definite integral:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n-1} \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}
\end{equation}

I'm really confused about tackling this. Although I know it is a Riemann sum, I don't really understand this and am hoping to seek a correct approach to this question. I tried using $t=1/n$ and replacing the limit by
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to 0+} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n-1} \frac{n^2}{n^2+k^2}t
\end{equation}
but I don't know what to proceed next.

I would appreciate some help/tips/hints on how to solve this. Many thanks!

Comment: $x\to\infty$ or $n\to\infty$ ?

Comment: @auntyellow Sorry! Fixed

Comment: Have you tried $x=1/n$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}$?

Comment: @auntyellow well yes, but as a beginner here I'm not really sure how to proceed next...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Rewrite then reindex the sum as follows

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n-1}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2} = -\frac{1}{2n}+\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}= -\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n^2+(k+n)^2}$$

The first term vanishes in the limit leaving the last term

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}+1\right)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your hint! I believe I can answer this question now.

Comment: I think to the sum you have to add is $\frac{-1}{2n}$ and not $\frac{-1}{n}$ (though it won't make a difference when you take the limit) and it might also help to add and subtract another term so that the sum is from $k = 0$ to $k = n$.

Comment: @PTrivedi yes you are right about the term, but the $0$ to $n$ part is incorrect

Comment: Ah yes my mistake. Either you want 0 to n-1 or 1 to n.

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite the sum as $$\sum_{k = n+1}^{2n-1}\frac{n}{n^2 + k^2} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k= n+1}^{2n-1} \frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2} = -\frac{1}{5n} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k= n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}.$$ I think you can take it from here.

> Then taking the limit makes the first summand vanish and the second one turns into the integral $$\int_1^2\frac{1}{1 + x^2}dx = \tan^{-1}(2) - \tan^{-1}(1).$$